# JQuery pagination onPageClick event continuously running

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, pagination

Lets say I have a div with ID "pagination-demo" with a `totalPage` settings of 5. Here is how I initialize it:

```
function InitializePagination(totalPage) {
    opts = {
        totalPages: totalPage,
        visiblePages: 5,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            request();
        }
    };

    $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination(opts);
}
```

The ajax request is:

```
function request() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "webservice.asmx/CaseStudiesList",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (r) {

            ('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination('destroy');
            $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination($.extend(opts, {
                totalPages: 10
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

The correct result would be to change the totalPages settings of JQuery pagination plugin from 5 to 10.

Now, whenever I click different page (thus invoking `onPageClick` function), the `request` function is being continuously called. Why and how can I force it to just be called once?

Comment: Why you need to call `request();` whenever click on page number? If you want it to just be called once. Just move `request()` function after `$('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination(opts);`

Comment: @SuTran Actually the function definition of `request` is something like 'request(categoryId, pageNo)'. I need the `onPageClick` returning value - `page` and pass it into request like 'request(page)'

Answer (score 0):

Here i can see `page` argument in the callback:

```
onPageClick: function (event, page) {
    if(page === this.totalpages){
        request();
    }
}
```

#### From the docs:

> Available event:
>   onPageClick: callback function
>   Function parameters >
>   event : object
>   page : the number of page

Comment: `totalpages` is undefined in mine

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.twbsPagination.defaults = {
        totalPages: 1,
        startPage: 1,
        visiblePages: 5,
        initiateStartPageClick: false,
        hideOnlyOnePage: false,
        href: false,
        pageVariable: '{{page}}',
        totalPagesVariable: '{{total_pages}}',
        page: null,
        /*first: 'First',*/
        prev: '<i class="icon-im-arrow-left"></i>',
        next: '<i class="icon-im-arrow-right"></i>',
        
        loop: false,
        onPageClick: null
 };
```

here  **initiateStartPageClick: false,**   initiateStartPageClick needs to be false to stop  the request function from getting continuously called.